# What is the significance of the black spot?

Tags: analysis, film-techniques, glass

Mid-way through M. Night Shyamalan’s movie, [*Glass (2019)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6823368/) , there is a blurry black spot on screen for a long time. It doesn’t stay in one fixed place nor is it present throughout the whole film, so it can’t be a problem with the projector’s optics at my local theatre.

It’s too obvious and gets too much screen time to plausibly be a smudge or optical defect on the camera lens either (it would undoubtedly have been noticed). So, it must be intentional, which begs the question:  why is it there? What is its meaning?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4429/49).

Comment: Could you specify where in the movie you see this black spot? For example which scene begins the black spot and when does it end its appearance?

Comment: My vague recollection is that it was on screen as Mr. Glass was orchestrating his escape from captivity. I’d have to see the film again to be more specific. It was on screen for several minutes.

Comment: Did it look like a cue mark? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_mark

Comment: I really cannot find out what spot you are referring to. Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no such spot.

I watched the movie yesterday, and found no spot. Today, I reviewed his escape orchestration, around 1h13m30, and saw nothing. This video compiles a few different parts of his escape, and no spot.

If you saw this at the cinema, I have to assume it's either a [cue mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_mark), as suggested by comments, or a faulty projector.

---

If you do find this mark in some of the HD digital versions, please post a time-stamp or screenshot.